# Cryogenic and vacuum safe cable labeling or tagging

Tags: vacuum, experimental-technique, radio-frequency, cryogenics

Not the most in depth of physics questions, yet this feels like the right community for trying to crowd-source this type of expertise.

Essentially it is a question for those of you experienced with cold, high vacuum systems, in particular dilution refrigerators. So let's say pressures $\approx 10^{-6}~\mathrm{mbar}$ and temperatures $<1~\mathrm{K}$. What kind of labeling system do you use for cables?

I'm working with a system that has several tens of coaxial lines (typically 0.086 inch or ~2.2 mm diameter), and is poised to have many times over that number in the next few years. Keeping track of which one is which is becoming a challenge. At room temperature, I  would simply use existing labeling systems, such as cable flags or clip on wire markers. Most of those would probably also work just fine cryogenically.

It is instead the vacuum component has me a bit worried. Many common plastics such as Nylon have significant outgassing, and I imagine the same holds for printed texts/numbers. With many lines, those internal leaks might start adding up.

I've seen some solutions in the form of ceramic beads, but those would require unsoldering the connectors to get them on, which I would rather not do either. What are your solutions? It can of course be simple, a color system like resistors is probably just as easy to work with as numbers/characters, after a bit of time. I was thinking of finding teflon tubes and cutting them open to click them on, but perhaps something slightly more sophisticated exists?

Comment: At $1\,\text{K}$, I would not expect any significant outgassing on a $10^{-6}\,\text{mbar}$ level. You should easily achieve pressures of $10^{-12}\,\text{mbar}$ and below, since all surfaces start acting as cryo pumps. The limiting factor will be the amount of room-temperature surfaces that "shoot" atoms to the cryogenic region. Sealed Penning-traps regularly achieve  $10^{-15}\,\text{mbar}$ and below (estimated from the life-time of stored anti protons), simply by immersing the trap in LHe.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. that is a fair point! I guess the main concern (which I did not specify very well) is that we have chips thermalized at the base temperature of the system and we want their surfaces to be free of e.g. water. So if at the end of the cooldown the pressure is still low but the outgassing resulted in more water freezing onto the chip, that would still be bad.

But maybe I am being paranoid here! The labels are at least 10cm away from the chip, and the chip is in an enclosure that only has very small openings to begin with. Plenty of other surfaces for any remaining water to freeze on

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution for many signal cables. In my case, I only have a few signal cables and simply wrap little metal wires around them. The number of windings is the channel number, and with copper and brass I have two different types (signal and high voltage), which is enough for me.

Also, I have a "switchboard" in my cryostat, which is simply a plastic piece where the cables pass by, all neatly lined up, so at that point I can count the channel number too. Redundancy is always good ;)

Comment: That's indeed a nice solution for a limited number of channels. Maybe with a few more metals I can do without colors altogether. Worth thinking about, although I'll need to make sure I do it neatly!

Answer (score 1):

We use little folded tabs of sticky Nomex tape and write labels on them with fine-tipped 'permanent' marker pens. I can't vouch for their stability at 1 K, but they are fine in systems operating at pressures down to at least 10-7 mbar and temnperatures down to 5-6 K, so I can't imagine the lower temperature would be an issue. Some of these labels have stayed in place for periods in excess of 10 years without problems.

Comment: Cool. Can you bake that?

Comment: We dont usually bake - as we have resin-impregnated superconducting coils in our systems. But I believe that the adhesive Nomex tape is OK to about 150 C. As an alternative, we sometimes use Kapton (polyamide) adhesive tape. I think that has a higher max. temperature, and in our experience it still 'sticks' at cryogenic temperatres, even after cycling.

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot! Sounds like it could be a good way to go. I'll look into this.